# Android Key or Browser Key for Place AutoComplete?

Tags: java, android, google-places-api, google-api-java-client

I am very new to android development and i got stuck in whether to use android key or browser key for place autocomplete for google place api. It would be very good if somebody can help since on google place api documentation(https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup) it is written that

***Note: You need an Android API key, not a browser key. You can use the same API key for your Google Maps Android API v2 apps and your Google Places API for Android apps.***

but at another place([http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application](http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/)/) it is written that

***Places API doesn’t work with Android or iOS API key***

Please Help !!!

Comment: link of Google Developer Note :[link](https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup)

Comment: Create SERVER key. and use it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the web service, use your browser key.  If you're using the Android library, use your Android key.